# Как сделать, чтобы сайт везде открывался в полном масштабе? То есть ширина всегда одна, но в зависимости от экрана сайт открывался по высоте

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, веб-интерфейс

HTML && CSS

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orelega+One&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600&display=swap');
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Orelega One', cursive;
  /*background: url(../images/background.jpg);
    padding: 100px 0;*/
  background: #f4f4f4;
  min-width: 1900px;
  height: 100%;
  margin 0 auto;
}


/*.container {
    width: 1200px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}*/

.header {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: 96px;
  background: white;
  line-height: 96px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 25px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 42px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}

a.button7 {
  line-height: 42px;
  margin-left: 70%;
  top: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 1px);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgb(64, 199, 129);
  box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(53, 167, 110) inset;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

a.button7:hover {
  background: rgb(53, 167, 110);
}

a.button7:active {
  background: rgb(33, 147, 90);
  box-shadow: 0 3px rgb(33, 147, 90) inset;
}

.main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin 0 auto;
}

.main-photo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  filter: blur(2px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 400px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) inset;
  background: url("../images/intro-image.jpg") center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #9EC1D4;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  top: 180px;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: -40px 30px 30px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.leftstr,
.rightstr {
  float: left;
  /* Обтекание справа */
  width: 50%;
  /* Ширина текстового блока */
  border-bottom: dotted 3px #9EC1D4;
  color: #626262;
}

.rightstr {
  text-align: right;
  /* Выравнивание по правому краю */
  color: black;
}

.contacts {
  position: relative;
  background: #148bff;
  top: 1000px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.address {
  position: absolute;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 35px;
  float: left;
  left: 20%;
}

.time {
  position: absolute;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 35px;
  left: 44%;
}

.phone {
  position: absolute;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 35px;
  float: right;
  right: 20%;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
  top: 1200px;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" content='width=1900' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
  <title>Труботорг</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="name">
      <h1>ТРУБОТОРГ</h1>
    </div>
    <a href="assets/download/price_trubotorg32.pdf" download="price_trubotorg32" class="button7">Скачать прайс</a>
  </div>

  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="main-photo"> </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2 align="center" style="font-family: 'Orelega One', cursive;">ООО "ДИЛАР"</h2>
      <p class="leftstr">Юридический адрес организации:</p>
      <p class="rightstr" style="text-align: left;">Россия, Брянская обл, г Брянск, ул Орловская, 30, 47</p>
      <p class="leftstr">ИНН:</p>
      <p class="rightstr" style="text-align: left;">3255053340</p>
      <p class="leftstr">ОГРН:</p>
      <p class="rightstr" style="text-align: left;">1063255031377</p>
      <p class="leftstr">КПП:</p>
      <p class="rightstr" style="text-align: left;">325701001</p>
      <p class="leftstr">Расчетный счет:</p>
      <p class="rightstr" style="text-align: left;">40702810610000305201</p>
      <p class="leftstr">Банк:</p>
      <p class="rightstr" style="text-align: left;">АО "ТИНЬКОФФ БАНК"</p>
      <p class="leftstr">Юридический адрес банка:</p>
      <p class="rightstr" style="text-align: left;">Москва, 123060, 1-й Волоколамский проезд, д 10, стр 1</p>
      <p class="leftstr">Корр.счет банка:</p>
      <p class="rightstr" style="text-align: left;">30101810145250000974</p>
      <p class="leftstr">ИНН банка:</p>
      <p class="rightstr" style="text-align: left;">7710140679</p>
      <p class="leftstr">БИК банка:</p>
      <p class="rightstr" style="text-align: left;">044525974</p>
      <div style="clear: left"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contacts">
    <h2 style="border-bottom: 0px; font-size: 50px; padding-top: 20px; color: aliceblue;" align="center">Контакты</h2>
    <div class="address">
      <h3 align="center" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 50px;">Адрес</h3>
      <p style="font-size: 24px; margin-top: 30px; color: #7EBFFF;">Склад</p>
      <p style="font-size: 24px; color: #7EBFFF;">г.Брянск пос.Октябрьский</p>
      <p style="font-size: 24px; color: #7EBFFF;">ул.Шоссейная 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="time" align="center">
      <h3 style="margin-top: 50px;">Время работы</h3>
      <p style="font-size: 24px; margin-top: 30px; color: #7EBFFF;">Пн—Пт: 9:00—17:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="phone" align="center">
      <h3 style="margin-top: 50px;">8 (4832) 78-29-54</h3>
      <h3>78-30-91</h3>
      <p style="font-size: 24px; margin-top: 30px; color: #7EBFFF;">dilar-bryansk@yandex.ru</p>
      <p style="font-size: 24px; color: #7EBFFF;">trubotorg-bryansk@ya.ru</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer" align="center" style="line-height: 50px; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 14px;">
    <p>Copyright © 2021. ТРУБОТОРГ.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй в `head` задать такой тег мета

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=ширина контейнера(без пикселей)">
```

Но при этом, у тебя должна быть задана фиксированная ширина контейнера.
Не знаю хороший это способ или нет, но думаю это то, что тебе нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Т.е, ты хочешь чтобы твой сайт выглядел нормально на всех устройствах? Тогда тебе нужно изучить метод css flexbox. Можешь прочитать [здесь](https://html5book.ru/css3-flexbox/#display-flex) что тебе нужно, я на своем найте использовал

```css
.flex{
display: flex;
width: 100%;
flex-flow: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

к div-ам, для того, что если маленький экран все они переносились на следующую строку и влезали

Comment: Мне нужно сделать не адаптацию, а чтобы вся ширина сайта открывалась, а не какая-то часть экрана, например на мобильных устройствах. Чтобы длина увелививалась, а от этого и ширина.